# OpenLayers map with multiple vector layers makes whole page blink in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map, which takes almost all page size. Also it has 13 vector layers on it. When I drag map with all layers enabled - the whole page starts blinking. It is reproduced only in chrome, in firefox everything looks fine. When I disable two layers - blinking stops. If I make map smaller - blinking stops. It looks like some kind of a chrome bug. My chrome version: 31.0.1650.8 beta-m

---

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHWV6/2/) to demonstrate the problem. Try set VECTOR_LAYERS_COUNT to 45 and you'll see the problem, also if you reduce width/height of map the blinking will stop even with 45 layers. Here is the code:

```
var VECTOR_LAYERS_COUNT = 25; // set to 45 to see result
for (var i = 0; i < VECTOR_LAYERS_COUNT; i++) {
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(i, {
        renderers: OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers,
        rendererOptions: {
            zIndexing: true
        },
        visibility: true,
    });
    mapa.addLayer(layer);
}
```

Comment: I do not have a solution to this bug, but I can certainly confirm that for 36 or less vector layers it works as-expected and above that it fails quite spectacularly.  This helped point me to a problem I was having with a product.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem in Chrome for the last couple of weeks.

This seems to be a known problem with OpenLayers and later versions of Chrome.

The workaround is to disable SVG rendering of layers.

Change the following line from

```
renderers: OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers,
```

to

```
renderers: ['Canvas', 'VML'],
```

This fixed the problem for me.

HTH

**UPDATE**

Turns out this isn't a solution to the problem. The problem lies in Chrome's compositing engine. I have have submitted a bug report to the chromium developers, and they have successfully verified and accepted the bug report.

I'm not sure when the developers will get around to fixing it, but at least there's something in the works.

For those following along at home, this is the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346621

Comment: I've tried your solution (http://jsfiddle.net/tHWV6/26/). The effect is a bit different, but white areas are still appearing around the map. Chrome version: 33.0.1750.91 beta-m.

Comment: Huh, you're right. I may have just hit some sweet spot in my implementation. None of the renderers work correctly in Chrome. VML is not supported, and both Canvas and SVG exhibit the same problem.

Comment: I have successfully determined this is a problem in Chrome, and have submitted and verified a bug report. I'm not sure when the developers will get around to fixing it, but at least there's something in the works.

Comment: Can you add a link to a bug report please?

Comment: Check above. I edited my answer and included the link.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, will be waiting for the bug fix.

Comment: I also have a similar issue with the chrome browser( _Version 36.0.1985.84 beta-m_) . However, with the chrome canary ( _Version 38.0.2064.0 canary_), the jsfiddle demo seems to work though.

Comment: @panalbish I'm working on dev channel and from version 37.0.2062.0 dev-m (64-bit) I guess problem was solved (on previous one it was still reproducible)